# Erlang bit indexing

Tags: list, binary, erlang, bitmask, bitstring

I am currently trying to learn erlang and what I am trying to do is to perform an operation on specific indices of an array stored in a bit array or int.  If there is a 0 in a position, the index into the array at that position is not used.

So envision the following:

```
Example the array is: [1, 3, 5, 42, 23]
My bit array is: 21 = 10101 in binary
so I'm using indicies 1,3,5
so I'm calling a function on [1, 5, 23]
```

my function is of the form

```
my_function(Array, BitArray) ->
    SubArray = get_subarray_from_bitarray(Array, BitArray),
    process_subarray(SubArray).
```

And I need help with the get_subarray_from_bitarray().  I know erlang has special syntax around bit strings (something like <<>>) so is there an efficient way of indexing into the bit array to get the indicies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most the time, Erlang works with lists and recursion, so I believe it's idiomatic to go through each bit individually rather than try to index each bit in an iterative manner.

[The documentation on how to work with bitstrings is here.](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html)  In order to create a bitstring from the number 21, we can write `<<21>>`.  Since the default type for a member of a binary is integer, and the default size for an integer is 8, it will yield a bitstring that looks like `00010101`.  If you want to specifically get the last N bytes of a value is `<<Value:N>>`.  In order to get the last 5 bits of 21, we can say `<<21:5>>` which will yield `10101`.

I wrote the following module to do what you want:

```
-module(bitmask).
-export([get_subarray_from_bitarray/2]).

get_subarray_from_bitarray(Bitstring, List) ->
  get_subarray_from_bitarray_loop(Bitstring, List, []).

get_subarray_from_bitarray_loop(_Bits, [], Gathered) ->
  io:format("End of list~n", []),
  lists:reverse(Gathered);
get_subarray_from_bitarray_loop(<<>>, _Others, Gathered) ->
  io:format("End of bitstring~n", []),
  lists:reverse(Gathered);
get_subarray_from_bitarray_loop(<<Bit:1, Rest/bitstring>>, [Item | Others], Gathered) ->
  io:format("Bit: ~w ~n", [Bit]),
  case Bit of
    1 -> get_subarray_from_bitarray_loop(Rest, Others, [Item | Gathered]);
    0 -> get_subarray_from_bitarray_loop(Rest, Others, Gathered)
  end.
```

The first 2 clauses return the final list when you run out of bits or items in the list.  The important bit syntax is in the head of the last clause, `<<Bit:1, Rest/bitstring>>`.  This sets the value of `Bit` to the value of the first bit in the bitstring, and `Rest` to the rest of the bitstring.  Depending on the value of Bit, we decide whether or not we add the current item to the list.

Example invocations below:

```
> bitmask:get_subarray_from_bitarray(<<21:5>>, [1, 3, 5, 42, 23]).   
Bit: 1 
Bit: 0 
Bit: 1 
Bit: 0 
Bit: 1 
End of list
[1,5,23]
> bitmask:get_subarray_from_bitarray(<<31>>, [1, 3, 5, 42, 23]).  
Bit: 0 
Bit: 0 
Bit: 0 
Bit: 1 
Bit: 1 
End of list
[42,23]
> bitmask:get_subarray_from_bitarray(<<5:3>>, [1, 3, 5, 42, 23]). 
Bit: 1 
Bit: 0 
Bit: 1 
End of bitstring
[1,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation of the `get_subarray_from_bitarray/2` function could be:

```
get_subarray_from_bitarray(Array, BitArray) ->
    gsb(Array, BitArray, []).

gsb(_, 0, R) -> lists:reverse(R);
gsb([A1|A2], B, R) ->
  NextR = if B band 1 /= 0 ->
     [A1|R];
  true ->
     R
  end,
  gsb(A2, B div 2, NextR).
```

I'm pretty sure it would be very nice with a list comprehension too. Left as an exercise for the reader :)